# Using NOAA API to find current ocean surface temperature(SST)

Tags: json, weather-api, noaa

I'm working on a project where I need to find the current ocean surface temperature(SST). I've come across a few APIs that seem to do this. The API provided by NOAA seems to be the correct direction, [THIS SITE](http://www.seatemperature.org/asia/philippines/sablayan.htm) successfully accesses the data I need. If anyone could direct my to find the SST JSON info provided by NOAA, I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is the link for the NOAA API
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices

Answer (score 2):

SST data is usually in a gridded data format. 
Most agencies will provide large atmospheric and ocean data sets in this format. 
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/sst/griddata.php.

I've been battling to try to find a way to convert these gridded files into a sensible JSON format so that I can plot the information on a Leaflet map, with not a lot of luck so far.

But to try and help you solve your problem you need to be able to answer the following:

- Does it have to be with NOAA?
- What is your application?
- What kind of accuracy are you looking for? You could try extract some information
  from http://sea-temperature.com/.

Comment: Any luck with the gridded to JSON format conversion? Thanks!

Comment: Not yet. I moved away from the project. Will probably take it up again in the future.

Comment: I found this, which appears to have ocean color offerings in json https://open.nasa.gov/blog/the-open-api-universe-at-nasa/

Comment: Also, check out `Worldview`, which is a n open source platform built on openlayers that is driven by json data. Pretty dang awesome. The github repo link is on the about page. https://earthdata.nasa.gov/labs/worldview/

Comment: One more thing... Have a look at `ncdump-json`. It worked for me, but the cmake is a little cruddy and can be problematic.